# How to get numbers just before key words?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
result = dict()
for i in ['ABC', 'DEF']:
    result[i] = re.findall('{0}(.*?)(\d+\.*\d*-*\d+\.*\d*.*?)'.format(i), 'ABC costs 40000-50000 dollars; the price of car DEF is 45600-80000, HIJ only needs 30000USD')
```

It returns:

```
{'ABC': [(' costs ', '40000-50000')], 'DEF': [(' is ', '45600-80000')]}
```

However, I want the following:

```
{'ABC': ['40000-50000'], 'DEF': ['45600-80000'], 'OTHERS' : ['30000']}
```

Note that keywords not equal `ABC` and `DEF` are regarded as `OTHERS`.
How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want actual JSON string output, or do you want some sort of Python data structure?

Comment: Python dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This approach does a top line find all to get all three letter abbreviations along with numeric values/ranges.  Then it uses a list comprehension combined with `zip` and `dict` to generate the dictionary you want.

```
inp = "ABC costs 40000-50000 dollars; the price of car DEF is 45600-80000, HIJ only needs 30000USD"
matches = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]{3}\b|\d+(?:-\d+)?', inp)
print(matches)
map_out = dict(zip([matches[i] for i in range(0, len(matches), 2)],
                   [matches[i] for i in range(1, len(matches), 2)]))
print(map_out)
```

This prints:

```
['ABC', '40000-50000', 'DEF', '45600-80000', 'HIJ', '30000']
{'HIJ': '30000', 'ABC': '40000-50000', 'DEF': '45600-80000'}
```